# Comparing expected values using moment-generating function

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following problem I can't figure out:

> Suppose that $Y$ is a random variable with moment-generating function $m(t)$
>
> If $X = Y - 2$, use the mgf of $X$ to show that $E(X) = E(Y) - 2$.

I already derived from a previous question if if the mgf of $Y$ is $m(t)$, the mgf of $X$ is $e^{-2t}m(t)$.

I've done the following so far:

> To get $E(X)$, take first derivative of mgf($X$) and set $t=0$
>
> $$mgf(X) = e^{-2t}(1 + e^t + e^{2t} + e^{3t} + \ldots )$$
>
> By product rule,
>
> $$\text{derivative } = (e^{-2t}(e^t + 2e^{2t} + 3e^{3t} + \ldots ) + (-2e^{-2t}(1 + e^t + e^{2t} + \ldots )$$
>
> at $t=0$, this equals $(1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots ) + (-2(1 + 1 + 1 + \ldots )$

Clearly this is not the result I want to show. I feel like I am definitely making a silly mistake somewhere. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To use the MGF to show that E(Y-2)=E(Y)-2? Which textbook suggests this?

Comment: @Did Wackerly's "Mathematical Statistics with Applications" 7th ed.

It is meant to be an exercise in the section on MGFs.

Comment: A rather convoluted one, then. There are so many more natural ways to practice with MGFs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dt} \exp(-2t)m(t)=-2\exp(-2t)m(t)+\exp(-2t)m'(t)$$

Evaluate at $t=0$, notice $m(0)=1$ and $m'(0)=E[Y]$,

hence $E[X]=-2+E[Y]$